# Can't install new Diawi link on my iPhone

Tags: ios, diawi

I am trying to install a new build on my iPhone 5c but I am still getting that old build there. I am doing the same on my other phones but it's getting installed successfully.

iPhone specs:

1. iphone 5c ---> iOS 10 and Xcode 7.3
2. other devices ---> iOS 9.3 and Xcode 7.3

Is it because of the updated iOS version in my 5c?

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, right.
I had also same problem.

There are some cases this is happening.

1. make sure you registered your UDID correctly and provisioning profile includes UDID of your device.
2. if you deliver the app built on iOS 9.x to iOS 10 devices, it will not be installed after downloading.
   In this case, you can build again with Xcode 8 and try.
3. Some times, build number occurred this issue. when you distribute next build, never forget you increase the build number.
   For example, earlier build number was 2, you should update it to 3 next time.
4. make sure you used provisioning profile for adhoc.

hope this will help you.
Sincerely

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Now its done.....after 5-6 attempts,the new build is installed.Don't know what was the issue.

Comment: did you go without building again?